# Error while login to production workbench using my credentials

Tags: login-errors

Iam getting an error while login to the production workbench environment, i can however login to the quality environment.Please find attached the error screen shot, looking forward for help in resolving this issue.

[image: error screen shot]
Regards,
Atul

Comment: This error message indicates that the org admin has either blocked the usage of workbench or has given access for workbench only for limited set of users. You need to reach out to the org admin to be able to login.

Comment: Thank you, Arut

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to authorize the app in your org, your profile, or your user to access the Workbench.

If you are the system administrator then please find the below steps to get the workbench access:

To authorize all users in the org, you can go to Setup > Manage Apps > Connected Apps, edit Workbench, and set Permitted Users to "All users may self-authorize."

To authorize usage just for your user profile (e.g. System Administrators), go to the same area, but click on the label of the app (Workbench), then add your profile to the list.

You could also add a permission set to the list, then add the permission set to your user account. This will enable access just for you.

Thank you!

Comment: Thank you , Shirisha